# Convert the character codes inside CDATA instead of the whole string

Tags: javascript, regex

`var str = '&amp;<![CDATA[&amp;]]><![CDATA[&amp;]]>&amp;';`

In the above string, I just want to convert only `&amp;` inside the CDATA not the all `&amp;`.

**Expected Output:** `&amp;<![CDATA[&]]><![CDATA[&]]>&amp;`

I tried below regular expression

`str.trim().replace(/^(\/\/\s*)?<!\[CDATA\[|(\/&amp;\/\s*)?\]\]>$/g, '&')`;

But above code is not working as expected. I am not good in regular expressions. I gone through different answers given in Stackoverflow. But, not able to find the better way to achieve the fix. Could you please guide me.

Comment: How is `str` created?

Comment: I recommend to correct/change the source instead of doing endless post parsing.

Comment: @JavaScript: Agreed. If OP doesn't has to fix already corrupted data, but generates that corrupted data himself. Then it'd be much better to not corrupt the data in the first place.

Comment: @adiga I am getting that `str` after `new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(generatedXML)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular string you can apply `/(?<=CDATA\[)[&a-z;]+(?=]])/g`

You can use positive lookbehind and lookahead:

- `(?<=CDATA\[)` is a positive lookbehind. Searches everything after **CDATA[**
- `(?=]])` is a positive lookahead. Searches everything before **]]**
- `[&a-z;]+` matches some text containing lowercase letters, **&** and **;**

If I've got your idea correctly, it would be better to use XML parsers to manipulate a document.

[Here](https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3ytwg8jzv) you can find a sample js code.

[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/eABbKx/1)

Comment: Actually I am converting the generated xml to string using `XMLSerializer`. When it is converted to string the & is changing to &amp; inside the CDATA

Comment: Regex lookbehind and lookahead are not universally supported. Consider a solution that does not require them, such as with nested replace.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace any `&amp;` in CDATA, regardless of what comes before and after (within CDATA):

```
str.trim().replace(/<!\[CDATA\[.*?\]\]>/g, m => m.replaceAll('&amp;', '&'));
```

results in

```
"&amp;<![CDATA[&]]><![CDATA[&]]>&amp;"
```

This first matches CDATA sections and replaces them with the result of a function, the function replaces all `&amp;` with `&`;

Because that function is only applied on CDATA sections, `&amp;`s outside of CDATA will not be changed.

Example with more characters in CDATA:

```
var str = '&amp;<![CDATA[Oh look at this: &amp; Haha!]]>&amp;';
str.trim().replace(/<!\[CDATA\[.*?\]\]>/g, m => m.replaceAll('&amp;', '&'));
```

result:

```
"&amp;<![CDATA[Oh look at this: & Haha!]]>&amp;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the data received it is better to fix the data upstream. If not, you can use nested replaces:

- outer replace identifies the `<![CDATA[...]]>`
- inner replace `&amp;` inside CDATA

Both use the `g` flag to replace multiple time.

```js
[
  '&amp;<![CDATA[&amp;]]><![CDATA[&amp;]]>&amp;',
  '&amp;<![CDATA[this &amp; that]]>&amp;'
].forEach(str => {
  let result = str.replace(/<!\[CDATA\[[^\]]*\]\]>/, m => m.replace(/&amp;/g, '&'));
  console.log(result);
});
```

Output:

```
&amp;<![CDATA[&]]><![CDATA[&amp;]]>&amp;
&amp;<![CDATA[this & that]]>&amp;
```